# How to access nodejs config parameter in angular side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

i have nodejs config file(backend) in which some configuration data is defined:

```
module.exports = {
    product: {
        name: 'Event'
    },
    server: {

            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: 8000
    },
    database: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 27017,
        db: 'EventExchange',
        username: '',
        password: ''
    },
    key:{
        privateKey: 'dufediioeduedhn',
        tokenExpiry: 1*30*1000*60   //1 hour
    },
    admin:{
        "username" : "admssin",
        "password" : "adminss123",
        "scope"    : "adamssin"
    }
};
```

i have to access `port` and `host`  parameter in angular(client side). how is it posssible ?
Thanks!

Comment: how???  explain whats the problem, what have you tried.

Comment: i need port and host from configuration file  in client side so that we don't need to change port and host manually every place in code. do if i will change port and host parameter in config file,it will automatically get change entire web applicdation.

Answer (score 4):

You have to send them in a response (by sending JSON).

After that you can parse it using Json.parse.

For ex : At node side create a rest api

```
 app.get('/getConfig/', function (req, res, next) {
//NOW FETCH YOUR CONFIG
//PUT THE CONFIG IN JSON
var myConfig={port:database.port,host:database.hoat}
res.json(myConfig);
});
```

Now call this api from your AngularJs code by using $http

for ex:

```
$http.get("/getConfig").success(function(data))
{
console.log(data);
console.log(data.port);
console.log(data.host);
}
```

Hope this will help you !! Cheers :)